# Upper bound for a ratio of gamma functions

Tags: gamma-function, ratio

I'm trying to find an upper bound for

$$\left|\frac{\Gamma(z_1+n)}{\Gamma(z_2+n)}\right|$$

with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$. It's equivalent to find an upper and lower bound for $\displaystyle \left|(z)_n\right|=\left|\frac{\Gamma(z+n)}{\Gamma(z)}\right|$ with $(-)_n$ pochhammer symbol.

Another way may be look for an upper and lower boun for $\displaystyle \left|\Gamma(z+n)\right|$.

Any help or references are wellcome.

Comment: The Digital Library of Mathematical Functions gives the upper bound $|\Gamma(z+a)/\Gamma(z+b)| \leq 1/|z|^{b-a}$ when $a\geq 0$, $b\geq a+1$, and $\Re(z)>0$  http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.E8

Comment: Thanks, but in my problem the complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ can be different. Can be useful in $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(z+n)}\right|$

Comment: The case of $\Gamma(z+a)/\Gamma(z)$ (or its inverse) is in-principle well-known, even from Watson's lemma rather than Stirling-Laplace: it is asymptotic to $1/z^a$ in right half-planes. (E.g., see my note http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/basic_asymptotics.pdf) So $(z)_n$ itself has a clear asymptotic in right half-planes. To have two truly independent $z_1,z_2$ is a substantially different question.